# Github Actions - Auto-merge main to protected random branch after merge to main completed

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions, workflow

I want to have a github workflow to merge main to my branch named develop after PR merged.

I have an error of pushing to **protected** branch -

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/develop.        
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.        
To https://github.com/blabla/blabla-repo
 ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/blabla/blabla-repo'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Maybe its not using the admin user?
I've also added the bypass option..
Still getting the error..

```
name: Auto merge PR from main/master to develop branch
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - master
    types: closed
jobs:
  merge-main-back-to-develop:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    timeout-minutes: 2
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.adminUserToken }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set Git config
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "temp@temp.com"
          git config --local user.name "temp"
      - name: Merge main back to develop
        run: |
          git fetch --unshallow
          git checkout develop
          git pull
          git merge --no-ff ${{ github.base_ref }} -m "Auto-merge master/main back to develop"
          git push --force
```

I have tried adding the user with this option but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Syntax: `GITHUB_TOKEN: ${secrets.adminUser}` => `GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.adminUser }}`

Comment: EDIT - Changed the code with your fix.

Tried it too now, same error :(

Comment: That was not the fix. It was just a syntactical issue. If it's the same error then there's some branch protection configuration that is not bypassed for the admin. You need to revise those and test again.

Comment: Is [Do not allow bypassing the above settings](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches#do-not-allow-bypassing-the-above-settings) checked?

Comment: @Azeem I am able to push changes with the same user outside of the workflow since he is admin in the repo and it bypass the protection, but through the workflow it fails.. 
So I am not sure if the issue is because its not using the right creds or something..

Comment: @Azeem Nope,
 nothing is checked besides -
Require a pull requst before merging + require approvals + allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests +allow force pushes to the specific admin

Comment: Right. Then, it should work. Is `secrets.adminUserToken` the PAT that you generated with the write permissions?

Comment: Also, I believe that this token needs to be part of the checkout step. See https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage for more details. It would be under `actions/checkout`'s `with: token: ${{ secrets.adminUserToken }}`.

Comment: @Azeem WORKS PERFECT! after using checkoutv3 and using the token as part of the checkout. thank you!

Comment: That's great! :) You're welcome! Yes, that `actions/checkout@v2` needs to upgrade to `@v3` due to NodeJS deprecated dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your PAT with the right permissions under `token` with your checkout step like this:

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.adminUserToken }}
```

See [Usage](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) for more details.